# Check form validity from inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which watches if a form is submitted (so I can style validations only after they hit submit).

The problem is I cant 'reset' the form after it's successfully submitted. How would I go about doing that?

```
'use strict';


app.directive('formSubmitted', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.formSubmitted = false;
      element.on('submit', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.formSubmitted = true;
        });
      });

      scope.$watch('formSubmitted', function(submitted) {
        if (submitted === true) {
          element.addClass('submitted');
        } else {
          element.removeClass('submitted');
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I've attempted to try to check $valid from inside the directive but it's not working (not even sure if that's the best way).

Like this...

```
  var form = scope[element[0].name];
  element.on('submit', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      if (form.$valid === true) {
        form.$setPristine();
        scope.formSubmitted = false;
      } else {
        scope.formSubmitted = true;
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'reset' form ?

Comment: The form itself uses this... `<form name="newLedgerEntry1" ng-submit="newLedgerEntry1.$valid && createLedgerEntry()" form-submitted novalidate>`, so you can see it won't successfully submit until it's $valid. Inside the directive I need to 'reset' the form once the form is submitted AND the form is $valid. Otherwise once its successful (and it comes time to add a new entry) the form will still show red validation errors.